# Error: It seems the App source is not there: '/usr/local/Caskroom/multibit/0.5.19/MultiBit.app'

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, software

I first moved Caskroom to new location

```
mv /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom /usr/local
for f in ~/Applications/*.app; do oldloc="$(readlink "$f")"; [[ -e $oldloc ]] || ln -sf "/usr/local${oldloc#/opt/homebrew-cask}" "$f"; done
```

Then tried to install MultiBit.app

```
   > brew cask install --verbose multibit
    ==> Downloading https://multibit.org/releases/multibit-classic/multibit-classic-0.5.19/multibit-classic-macos-0.5.19.dmg
    Already downloaded: /Users/john/Library/Caches/Homebrew/multibit-0.5.19.dmg
    ==> Verifying checksum for Cask multibit
    Error: It seems the App source is not there: '/usr/local/Caskroom/multibit/0.5.19/MultiBit.app'
    Error: Kernel.exit
    > rm /Users/john/Library/Caches/Homebrew/multibit-0.5.19.dmg
    > brew cask install --verbose multibit
    ==> Downloading https://multibit.org/releases/multibit-classic/multibit-classic-0.5.19/multibit-classic-macos-0.5.19.dmg
    /usr/bin/curl -fLA Homebrew-cask v0.51+ (Ruby 2.0.0-648) https://multibit.org/releases/multibit-classic/multibit-classic-0.5.19/multibit-classic-macos-0.5.19.dmg -C 0 -o /Users/john/Library/Caches/Homebrew/multibit-0.5.19.dmg.incomplete
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100 32.4M  100 32.4M    0     0  1604k      0  0:00:20  0:00:20 --:--:-- 1886k
    ==> Verifying checksum for Cask multibit
    Error: It seems the App source is not there: '/usr/local/Caskroom/multibit/0.5.19/MultiBit.app'
    Error: Kernel.exit
> ls -al /usr/local/Caskroom/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  29 john  staff  986 Jun 26 13:05 .
drwxr-xr-x  22 john  wheel  748 Jun 26 12:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x   5 john  staff  170 Jan  2 15:43 appcleaner
drwxr-xr-x   3 john  staff  102 Mar 19 11:28 bettertouchtool
drwxr-xr-x   4 john  staff  136 May 25 19:30 cryptomator
drwxr-xr-x   3 john  staff  102 Mar 19 11:29 cyberduck
drwxr-xr-x   4 john  staff  136 May 25  2015 disk-inventory-x
drwxr-xr-x   6 john  staff  204 Jan  2 16:00 firefox
drwxr-xr-x   5 john  staff  170 Jan  2 16:01 flash
drwxr-xr-x   4 john  staff  136 Jan 29  2015 google-chrome
drwxr-xr-x   4 john  staff  136 Oct  3  2015 google-earth
drwxr-xr-x   4 john  staff  136 Apr 30 21:00 hacker-menu
drwxr-xr-x   5 john  staff  170 Jan  2 21:29 handbrake
drwxr-xr-x   5 john  staff  170 Jan  2 21:31 java
drwxr-xr-x   3 john  staff  102 Mar 19 11:29 kitematic
drwxr-xr-x   3 john  staff  102 Mar 19 11:29 mediathekview
drwxr-xr-x   4 john  staff  136 Mar 19 11:29 miro-video-converter
drwxr-xr-x   3 john  staff  102 Mar 19 11:29 mongohub
drwxr-xr-x   3 john  staff  102 Mar 19 11:29 mpeg-streamclip
drwxr-xr-x   3 john  staff  102 Mar 19 11:29 namechanger
drwxr-xr-x   3 john  staff  102 Mar 19 11:29 paintbrush
drwxr-xr-x   3 john  staff  102 Mar 19 11:29 robomongo
drwxr-xr-x   4 john  staff  136 Jul 12  2015 skreenics
drwxr-xr-x   5 john  staff  170 Jan  2 21:34 thunderbird
drwxr-xr-x   4 john  staff  136 Jun 26 11:07 torbrowser
drwxr-xr-x   4 john  staff  136 Jan 27  2015 transmission
drwxr-xr-x   4 john  staff  136 Mar 19 11:29 vienna
drwxr-xr-x   6 john  staff  204 Jan  2 21:36 virtualbox
drwxr-xr-x   5 john  staff  170 Jan  2 21:37 vlc
> ls /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom
ls: /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom: No such file or directory
```

My brew installation looks fine

```
> brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
    cf-cli
```

is this a bug or user error?

Answer (score 11):

I had this with two apps. It happened because I removed them via the Applications folder, using the finder.

> Error: Problems with multiple casks:
> darktable: It seems the App source '/Applications/darktable.app' is not there.

I got rid of this message by removing the application from cask:

```
brew cask remove darktable
==> Uninstalling Cask darktable
==> Purging files for version 3.0.2 of Cask darktable
```

**Update (December 2022)**

In the newer versions of brew, the above command should be as follows:

```
brew remove --cask darktable
==> Uninstalling Cask darktable
==> Purging files for version 3.0.2 of Cask darktable
```

Comment: The latest version of brew no longer requires cask; so it is just `brew remove darktable`

Comment: These days you may have to do something like `brew uninstall darknote`. I hope this helps